# openshift origin latest - make mongodb accessible to external resources

Tags: mongodb, openshift-origin

I'm running a small openshift cluster and would like to provide our developers with an hosted instance of mongo on it, which they connect to externally.

Which is easy enough, I thought. Sadly it still looks like all traffic has to go over haproxy and is limited to http/https. But my developers need to transparently access the correct mongo port 27017.

is there some way to expose the internal pod port, to the outside world, without knowing which pod it run on.

right now our dirty workaround is

oc port-forward mongodb-1-2n1ov 27017:27017

and than the client does a ssh forwarding from there machine to this.

instead we would rather have an automated solution that allows tcp forwarding for virtual defined hostnames.

could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: It's possible today with a little bit of work (similar to the solution mentioned below about exposing the services directly).  You can define a virtual cidr in your network that is routed to your routers (or any HA set of IPs).  On those hosts the service proxy would be running.  For each service you want to expose to the edge, set its externalIP to one of the IPs in your virtual CIDR, and give that externalIP it's own DNS name.  The service proxy will move that traffic to the pods.  One downside - today there is no control over who can set the externalIP field.

Comment: Yeah, same here. I wanted to the same with MySQL. I think the problem with portforwarding like that is that you forward directly to a pod. IMHO ideally we would forward to the Service. The benefit of this would be to be able to work with DB pods without knowing whom you talking to. You can scale as you wish. Of course you'd also need a solution to sticky sessions.

Comment: i aggree with dave and Clayton thanks, but guess I have to read up more. I'm mostly a software developer and tinker very very little with sys administration.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. We too had similar issue and only other way we though was to update the serviceCIDR which was routable within our network. We did not go that route though. HAProxy is http/https..while the services do support tcp/udp and mongodb:27017 relies on UDP.
I too would like to know more about this if anyone else can share.